# 500 error upon require_once('usercake/models/config.php')

Tags: php, require-once, http-status-code-500, usercake

I have a file with one line: `<?php require_once('usercake/models/config.php'); ?>`, and it gives me a `500` error. What could be the reason for this? My usercake installation is not modified in any way.

Comment: 500 is an error code dealing with permissions. Does your file have access to config.php?

Comment: permission of all files are set to 666

Comment: try printing DOC_ROOT. also, use this line at the start ini_set('display_errors', true);

Comment: DOC_ROOT appears not to be defined (`echo DOC_ROOT` prints the string `"DOC_ROOT"`). i get these errors: 
`Warning: require_once(models/languages/en.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/sem/usercake/models/config.php on line 42`
 and 
`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'models/languages/en.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/sem/usercake/models/config.php on line 42` . The `models/languages/en.php` file exists.